# self.window is always nil

Tags: macos, swift

I'm currently trying to display a window with a window controller.
That is what I have:

NSWindow subclass

```
import Cocoa
import CoreLocation

class TweetWindow: NSWindow {

var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var geoCoder: CLGeocoder!

@IBAction func tweetButtonPressed(sender:NSButton) {

}

func initialize() {
    self.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager();
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;

    self.geoCoder = CLGeocoder();
}

func windowWillShow() {
    if !self.visible {
        let systemAppearanceName = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("AppleInterfaceStyle") ?? "Light").lowercaseString;
        let systemAppearance = systemAppearanceName == "dark" ? NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark) : NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight);
        self.appearance = systemAppearance;

        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();
    }
}

func windowWillClose() {
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation();
}
}
```

NSWindowController subclass:

```
import Cocoa

class TweetWindowController: NSWindowController {

var tweetWindow: TweetWindow { return self.window as! TweetWindow; }

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    self.tweetWindow.initialize()
    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}

override func showWindow(sender: AnyObject?) {
    self.tweetWindow.windowWillShow()
    super.showWindow(sender)
}
}
```

Of course, I've got a .xib-file, too, that contains my window. It is called "TweetWindow.xib".
Now, so far this should be ok.

In my AppDelegate.swift I do the following:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

var tweetWindowController:TweetWindowController!;

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    tweetWindowController = TweetWindowController(windowNibName: "TweetWindow");
}

func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

func showTweetWindowInternal() {
    NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true);
    tweetWindowController.showWindow(nil);
}

@IBAction func showTweetWindow(sender: AnyObject) {
    showTweetWindowInternal();
}

@IBAction func quitApp(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self);
}
}
```

My problem is the following:
When I try to click on my button that is associated with the IBAction down there to show the window, an exception is thrown here:
*var tweetWindow: TweetWindow { return self.window as! TweetWindow; }*

It says *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*, so *window* is nil.

Why is window nil there? Am I trying to access the value too early or something?

Here are some photos:

[image: Window]

[image: File's Owner]

[image: File's Owner Identity Inspector]

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initializing an instance of `NSWindowController` or a subclass does **not** load the NIB. The NIB is not loaded until the `window` property is accessed or the `showWindow()` method is called (which basically accesses the `window` property indirectly). In your case, since you're overriding `showWindow()`, it's important to know that the NIB is not loaded until the superclass implementation is called.

So, yes, your call to `self.tweetWindow.windowWillShow()` in your `showWindow()` override, before calling through to super, is too early. The NIB has not been loaded at that point, so the `window` outlet has not been connected to anything.

Of course, you have to make sure the outlet is actually connected in the NIB or it will never be connected, even after the NIB is loaded. But trying to access it before it's loaded is the first problem.

I think your `windowWillShow()` method is misguided, at least as implemented. The window can be shown in various ways, not just by the window controller's `showWindow()` method. For example, something outside of both the window and the window controller could do `tweetWindowController.window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)`. If you really want to do something like this, have the window class override the various `order...()` methods to see if the window is being ordered in for the first time and, if so, call your method.

---

Update:

You have several things misconfigured in your NIB. Here's what you need to do to fix them:

- Break the current connection from the "delegate" outlet of File's Owner to the window. Click the "x" button seen in either of the screenshots you posted.
- Change the class of File's Owner. It is currently `TweetWindow`. It should be `TweetWindowController`. The controller is what loads and owns the NIB, so the class of File's Owner should be the controller class.
- Connect the "window" outlet of File's Owner to the window.
- Connect the "delegate" outlet of the window to File's Owner.

Comment: I removed the overriden function ("showWindow") but it still throws me the exception in "windowDidLoad". It seems that the outlet is failing or something like that. I connected the delegate to the File's Owner but no changes.

Comment: "I connected the delegate to the File's Owner" The important thing is not that the window's delegate is connected to File's Owner. It's that File's Owner's window outlet is connected to the window. Other things to check: the class of File's Owner in the window NIB is `TweetWindowController`, right? Did you perhaps instantiate another instance of that class in the NIB? That is, did you drag an "Object" into the NIB and set its class to `TweetWindowController`? If so, delete that from the NIB.

Comment: I changed that so that the outlet delegate of the File's Owner now refers to the window. The class of File's Owner has been "TweetWindow". I tried it with TweetWindowController, but the exception still appears. But that wouldn't make sense then anyway, would it? I have no other objects that have set "TweetWindowController" as class in my NIB, so it is not possible that this is the source of the exception, I think.

Comment: Is there any place in your code, other than `applicationDidFinishLaunching()`, that you instantiate `TweetWindowController`? You may need to update your question with the current code, screenshots of the NIB document outline, the Identity inspector of File's Owner, and the Connections inspector of both File's Owner and the window.

Comment: I am only creating one instance of it in my program. I updated my question above and added some photos.

Comment: File's Owner has the wrong class. Its class should be `TweetWindowController`. The controller loads and owns the NIB, so it is File's Owner. The window is *in* the NIB, so can't be its owner. Once you change the class, File's Owner will have a `window` outlet, which you should connect to the window. The fact that this was not connected is the root of your problem. Also, File's Owner will no longer have a `delegate` outlet because `TweetWindowController` doesn't (and shouldn't). Xcode won't automatically break the existing connection; you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: To clarify that last point: you want to **keep** the connection *from* the window's `delegate` outlet *to* File's Owner. You want to break the connection from the spurious `delegate` outlet of File's Owner to the window, though, because File's Owner doesn't really have any such outlet.

Comment: It automatically adds that connection to the File's Owner once the outlet delegate of the window is connected to it.

Comment: Your screenshots show **none** of the window's outlets connected. They also show that a "delegate" outlet of File's Owner is connected to the window. (In one screenshot, you're seeing an outlet, in the other screenshot you're seeing the same connection as a "referencing outlet". That is, an outlet of some other object which references this one.) As I say, File's Owner should not even have a "delegate" outlet, let alone have it connected to the window. File's Owner should have a "window" outlet connected to the window. You have to fix its class first, so see that.

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense. I fixed the misconfigurations and now it works.
Now I understand what these connections mean. Thanks!